# Discord.py input convert to int()

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

how can i convert input to int() on discord ?

Example:

```
input = await bot.wait_for("message")
```

i was try to did convert like `int(answer)`

Thanks.

Edit: Getting error `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'Message'`

Comment: What happened when you tried that? Why `answer` and not `input` as declared here?

Comment: im getting error ```TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'Message' ```

Comment: Sounds like the user didn't input a number, so you can't convert it.

Comment: have you tried it like this 
`result = int(input.content)`?

Comment: Because i couldn't convert discord input to int()

Comment: I added it as an answer, if it resolved it please accept the answer so that i can help others.

Comment: i did thanks for your attention.

Comment: `input` is the name of a built-in method, don't use it as a variable name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can convert it to int -

```
# Convert the input to an integer
result = int(input.content)
```